dbt macro is picking up the wrong relation
I am trying to build a macro which selects all columns, and validates that a set of columns is present in a seed file or model, and add them if not present.
My macro looks basically like this:
{% macro get_validated_columns(relation, required_fields=["created_at", "updated_at"]) -%}

{%- set model_fields = adapter.get_columns_in_relation(relation) -%}
{%- for field in model_fields %}
    {% if not loop.first %}, {% endif %}{{ field }}
{% endfor -%}

{%- for required_field in required_fields %}
    {% if field not in model_fields -%} , null as {{ required_field }} {%- endif %}
{%- endfor -%}
{%- endmacro -%}

I have a seed file test_model.csv, and a staging view which looks like
-- stg_test_model.sql

{%- set relation = ref('test_model') -%}

select {{ get_validated_columns(relation) }}
from {{ relation }}

The problem is when I run this I get a failure because no fields are found in relation. I added a log line in the macro
{{ log("Found fields: ~ model_fields ~ " in " ~ relation, info=true) }}

and to the model
{{ log("Building: " ~ relation, info=true) }}

This returns the log lines
Building: `hive_metastore`.`field_validation_test`.`stg_test_model`
Found fields:  in `hive_metastore`.`field_validation_test`.`stg_test_model`

I don't understand why it is looking in the stg_test_model instead of the provided ref('test_model') relation which should point to the seed file.
Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Small update. If I remove the macro from the select and instead just select *, I get the same error... however if I partial parse (dbt compile --partial-parse) I get a success and the log message I expect
Partial parsing with the macro call does not help though.
